Why doesn't static friction adjust itself to cancel motion in this 2 block system?

We have to find the acceleration of the blocks.
Let's do the math first and then I will ask my question.
For there to be kinetic friction, the force applied in horizontal ($4 \ \text{N}$) must be greater than maximum static friction.
The maximum static friction on a $3 \ \text{kg}$ block is $\mu N$, where $\mu$ is $0.3$ (given) and $N$ can be calculated using Newton's second law.
As there is vertical equilibrium:
$$N = 3g+20 \ \text{N} = 30 \ \text{N} +20 \ \text{N} = 50 \ \text{N},$$
so maximum static friction is $0.3 \times 50 \ \text{N} =15 \ \text{N}$, but as the horizontal force is $4 \ \text{N}$, which is less than $15 \ \text{N}$, no sliding will take place and there will be static friction, and both blocks will move together. Let friction be $f$. By Newton's 2nd law:
$$4 \ \text{N}-f=3a \tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
$$f=7a \tag{2}\label{eq:2}.$$
By \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}:
\begin{aligned}
4 \text{N} &= 10 a \\
a &= \frac{2}{5} \ \mathrm{m/s^2}.
\end{aligned}
I don't understand that, as we calculated, the maximum static friction is $15 \ \text{N}$, and the force applied horizontally is just $ 4 \ \text{N}$. Why wouldn't then the static friction adjust itself to become $ 4 \ \text{N}$?
Why is there any movement at all? Here by \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}, $f = 2.8 \ \text{N}$, but it could also have been $4 \ \text{N}$ (its max was $15 \ \text{N}$). Why doesn't it do that?
If we consider this case

then we know that the $3 \ \text{kg}$ block won't move at all as the static friction will adjust itself to $ 4 \ \text{N}$. The force in red and in horizontal direction should at least be $ 15 \ \text{N}$ to cause any acceleration.
Summary: My question is, why doesn't the static friction adjust itself to $ 4 \ \text{N}$ in the 1st question also? I wish to understand this deeply and fundamentally.
My views: I said fundamentally because if, let's say, the friction balanced itself to become $ 4 \ \text{N}$, then there will be no acceleration on the $ 3 \ \text{kg}$ block but on the $ 7 \ \text{kg}$ block there will be a net force of $ 4 \ \text{N}$, so it will start to move. But for it to move (when it starts moving, friction changes direction) it must get rid of the static friction of the $ 3 \ \text{kg}$ block. But the paradox is that this static friction itself is causing it to move.
Please help.

There will be no movement along the blocks

Do you mean to say there will be no relative movement?

"For there to be kinetic friction, the force applied in horizontal (4 N) must be greater than maximum static friction." This doesn't influence the question, but be aware that this statement generally is incorrect. Yes, a stationary object won't move until the static friction limit has been reached. But the kinetic friction that then takes over is typically lower. That's why we see stick-slip phenomena. So, whether we have static or kinetic friction also depends on whether the force is reducing or increasing towards the static friction limit. Just FYI.

There is no law stating that static friction will try to prevent motion or acceleration. There is only a law stating that it will try to prevent relative motion.
Sure, $4 \,\mathrm N$ is what is needed for static friction to prevent the upper block from accelerating. But static friction has no intention of doing that. It turns out that $2.8\,\mathrm N$ is enough to pull the lower block along with the upper block such that no sliding - no relative motion - happens. So why would static friction increase above that value?
The answer is, it won't. And this should resolve the paradox.
Essentially, the $2.8\,\mathrm N$ acts backwards on the upper block and forwards on the lower block due to Newton's 3rd law. This amount of backwards force will reduce the acceleration of the upper block a bit, but not to zero. And this amount of forwards force increases the acceleration of the lower block a bit. The end result is that they now have the same acceleration and speed. So, there will be no relative motion. And static friction is happy.


But the paradox is that this static friction itself is causing it to move.

I believe that this statement is the core of the confusion that you are facing. You understand that the force of static friction adjusts (within its limits) to any value that is needed to prevent something. However, you are mistaken in what it prevents.
The force of static friction does not prevent "motion". Instead, it prevents "slipping". That is a critical distinction.
Very often, preventing slipping requires producing motion. So static friction causing something to move is not at all paradoxical, it is a consequence of preventing slipping.
For example, it is very difficult to walk on ice because there is so little static friction and your foot often slips on the ground. Without that friction preventing slipping, it is difficult to move. Similarly with a car on ice. In both cases static friction is needed for the overall motion of the object.
Consider also a box on the bed of a truck (with no railing). If the bed of the truck is something like rubber, then the static friction will be high, the box will not slip, and it will move with the truck as the truck accelerates. If the bed of the truck is smooth, then the static friction will be low, the box will slip, and it will not move with the truck as the truck accelerates.
In this problem, the static force of friction prevents slipping between the top and bottom block. Because there is no slipping the two blocks must move together. This is not a paradox, it is how static friction works.

Why wouldn't then the static friction adjust itself to become 4 N ? Why is there any movement at all?

Again, static friction prevents slipping, it does not prevent movement. A static friction force of $4 \mathrm{\ N}$ would prevent the top block from moving, but the bottom block would accelerate at $4/7 \mathrm{\ m/s^2}$. The blocks would therefore slip which is not how static friction behaves. Static friction will produce motion in order to prevent slipping, so the force is not $4 \mathrm{\ N}$.

I believe you misunderstood what I meant to say. I didn't mean to say that static friction doesn't cause movement. I meant to say that for the 7kg block(in the case we assume static friction be 4N), is moving forward with acceleration 4/7 right, so it has some velocity forward and relative to 3kg box(its stationary in the case), so the direction of friction reverses due it the movement of 7kg box, and 3kg box will NOW prevent motion of the 7kg block but its paradoxical since INITIALLY it was causing the movement through friction

Could you give a mathematical explanation, possibly through newton's laws, why the 3kg block in the 2nd diagram i made will not move, but in the 1st diagram will move, even though all the forces and their direction on the 3kg block(that's what i think) will be same. Thanks

@KhushivBatra i have added a paragraph to my answer. You still seem to be missing the difference between "motion" and "slipping".

Yes @Dale you are right, I was clearly misunderstanding

You can often think of static friction as glue. The two blocks are stuck together. The lateral force required to separate them is determined by the coefficient of static friction, and if that is exceeded then the "glue" breaks and they slip. Unless that coefficient is exceeded, there's no difference (that affects this question) between static friction and the internal forces holding each block in once piece. Unlike those internal forces, the vertical force to break the glue by lifting the top block is "anything over zero" (plus the weight of the top block, if you want to include that).

So, you draw the force diagram the same way you would draw the force diagram between the "top 30%" of a single block which is being pulled, and the "bottom 70%" of that single block, which is pulled along with it. The 30/70 split of course would be completely arbitrary for a single block, but the only difference with two blocks is that 30/70 is the point at which we need to check whether or not static friction is overcome. Any weakness in a single block could be treated similarly in a force diagram to check whether the weakness will break.


but it could also have been $4 \ \text{N}$ (its max was $15 \ \text{N}$). Why doesn't it do that?

It couldn’t have been $4 \ \text{N}$ because then the acceleration of the lower block would be, per Newton’s 2nd law, $4/7=0.57 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$, making it different from the upper block.
In order to determine the actual static friction force you must consider all the constraints of the problem, not just the force applied to the upper block. To say static friction adjusts based only on the external force applied to the upper block is an oversimplification, because the static friction force only prevents relative motion (slipping) between the surfaces, not motion in general.
FIG 1 below are free body diagrams of both the upper and lower block, given they have moved together with the same acceleration (the maximum static friction force of $15 \ \text{N}$ between the blocks is not exceeded).
If the upper block was directly on the ground with the same coefficient of static friction, then the static friction force would match the applied force and the block wouldn’t move. See FIG 2 below.
Hope this helps.



I have written in my remark that it couldn't be 4N myself but I want to know how. We cannot assert the conclusion as the reason. Its not written in the original question that the acceleration of lower block must be same as lower block, we figured that out. I still dont understand why friction doesn't adjust

@KhushivBatra see update to my answer

I understand what you mean to say, but could you give a mathematical explanation or FBD of the 3kg blocks in the 1st diagram and the 2nd diagram, to let me know how are the forces different in the 2nd diagram than in the 1st diagram(as the 3 kg block is same in both diagrams, ofcouse the forces must be different as one block is accelerating and other is not). Thanks

Sure. I'll include FBDs

If both blocks move as a single unit to the right, the acceleration of both blocks together is $$a = \frac{F}{m} = \frac{F}{(3+7)} = 0.4 \ \mathrm{m/s^2},$$ which is the same as the result you got ($a = 2/5 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$). This means the net force acting on the top block is $$F_T = m a = 3 \times 0.4 = 1.2 \ \text{N}.$$ The net force acting on the top block is also equal to $$F_T = 4 \ \text{N} - f,$$ where $f$ is the static friction acting between the blocks. This means the static friction is $$f = 4 \ \text{N}- F_T = 4 \ \text{N} - 1.2 \ \text{N} = 2.8 \ \text{N}.$$ This static friction acts on the lower block, and the acceleration of the bottom block is $$a_B = \frac{f}{m_B} = \frac{2.8 \ \text{N}}{7 \ \text{kg}} = 0.4 \ \mathrm{m/s^2},$$ which agrees with the acceleration we calculated for the two block assembly.

Summary: My question is, why doesn't the static friction adjust itself
to $4 \ \text{N}$ in the 1st question also?

It is the static friction that transfers the force from the top block to the bottom block, and it is less than the $4 \ \text{N}$ applied to the top block because part of the $4 \ \text{N}$ is 'used up' accelerating the top block.

I have written in my remark that it couldn't be $4 \ \text{N}$ myself, but I want
to know how. We cannot assert the conclusion as the reason. It's not
written in the original question that the acceleration of (upper)
block must be the same as the lower block; we figured that out. I still don't
understand why friction doesn't adjust – Khushiv Batra

You calculated that the maximum static friction between the blocks is $15 \ \text{N}$, and this is the force that must be exceeded for the blocks to move relative to each other. Since the applied horizontal force is $4 \ \text{N}$, we can conclude that the blocks do not move relative to each other and must move as a single block. We can calculate everything else from there.

Why wouldn't then the static friction adjust itself to become $4 \ \text{N}$? Why
is there any movement at all?

Imagine we nail the $3 \ \text{kg}$ block to the $7 \ \text{kg}$ block. It will now act as a $10 \ \text{kg}$ block. Do you really believe that if we apply $4 \ \text{N}$ to the combined $3 \ \text{kg}$ block and there is no friction between the combined block and the ground, the $3 \ \text{kg}$ block will not move? What is stopping it? With no friction acting at the ground interface, the combined block must accelerate at $$a = \frac{F}{m} = \frac{4}{10} = 0.4 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}.$$ Agree? Now, if we remove the nail and the static friction is sufficient to prevent the top block from moving relative to the lower block, the two blocks will still move together. The removal of the nail cannot increase the friction between the combined block and the frictionless ground surface, can it? Agree? How can you stop the combined block moving when you apply $4 \ \text{N}$ of force to it, and there is no friction at the base? The more interesting question is: why does the static friction reduce from $4 \ \text{N}$ to $2.8 \ \text{N}$ when the lower $7 \ \text{kg}$ block is accelerating?
Let's put it another way. Imagine we have a solid $10 \ \text{kg}$ block of wood sitting on a frictionless ground surface, and we want to prevent the $10 \ \text{kg}$ block from moving when a $4 \ \text{N}$ horizontal force is applied to it. We cannot achieve that goal by sawing the big block into a $3 \ \text{kg}$ block on top of the $7 \ \text{kg}$ block. This does not change the fact the ground surface is still a frictionless surface.
In summary, the job of static friction between two objects is to prevent the two objects from moving relative to each other (when the force trying to make the objects move relative to each other is less than the maximum limit of the static friction). Static friction by itself cannot prevent the two objects from moving altogether. To prevent the two objects from moving relative to the ground, there would have to be another external force acting in the opposite direction or static friction between the two objects and the ground.

I dont understand how its 'used up'. Friction is just horizontal component of contact force which follows the action and reaction pair. The magnitude of friction that 7kg block applies on 3kg block is same as the force of friction that 3kg block applies on 7kg block. So friction to the 3kg block was initially provided by the 7kg block itself only, how could it be 'used up' by 7kg block itself then?

The 2.8N of friction force provided by the 7kg block reduces the net force acting on the 3kg block to 4-2.8 = 1.2N. The reaction force to the 2.8N of friction force is the force that accelerates the 7Kg block.  At the contact interface between the two blocks, there is an action and reaction pair that consists of the friction and the reaction to it.  Since the action and reaction forces are equal and opposite there is no acceleration of the blocks relative to each other and they accelerate together as one.

If the static friction between the blocks was 4N and this is acting in the opposite direction to the applied horizontal force of 4N the net force acting on the 3 kg block would be zero and it would not accelerate at all, when clearly it is co-accelerating with the lower block.

Could you compare the FBD of the 3kg block in the 2nd diagram than in the 1st diagram, because I think the forces are same on the 3 kg block in both the diagrams but since the acceleration is not same, ofcourse they need to be different. What mistake I am making in FBD of the 3kg block in the 2 diagrams.

"What mistake I am making in FBD of the 3kg block in the 2 diagrams." You have not drawn in the friction forces and reactions to them at the interface between the top block and the lower block and between the lower block and the ground. Your FBDs are incomplete and do not show all the horizontal forces. P.S. I have extended my answer.
